# Android button open link in background?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am looking to build a button in my android app that when the user clicks on the button, it'll load a URL in the background without the user seeing the page it loaded.
(the url sets off something in my api, if someone loads the url it triggers my api to do x thing, thats why I need it.)

I looked around and could not find anything useful already.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: search for  *how to do a http request in Android*

Comment: Thanks, will research that.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the the page using volley library from service.

Comment: I'd have to redo it, started over.
was making me super mad <_>

Answer (score 0):

Without providing any **progress bar** or **loader** in Async task the users doesn't recognize that the page is loading.
Why the user need to click that button(i.e. you may make user to click that button for some other action right?)